Is this algorithm considered greedy?
The problem:
Given a list of n cities, each one at distance D[i] from the beginning of a positive half-axis, find
the least possible number of antennas, each one having a radius r, so that every city is within the radius of an antenna.
Find a greedy algorithm of O(n) complexity.
My approach:
My first thought was to take each city, starting from the beginning of axis, and if it is not within the radius of an antenna, place an antenna in distance r after the city. Which seems an optimal solution (haven't tried proving it yet).
I am not sure though, that this is considered a greedy algorithm.

A greedy algorithm is defined as an algorithm that follows the
problem-solving heuristic of making the locally optimal choice at each
stage.

My question:
So in the case of this problem, won't the locally optimal choice be to place an antenna so that it reaches the most cities, therefore my algorithm is not greedy?

Not entirely sure that "greedy" is all that well defined.  To the extent that it is, I'd tend to agree that "greedy" here would mean "place each new antenna where it covers the most cities".  But the algorithm you proposed initially is interesting and it would be good to confirm that it was, in fact, optimal.

Your approach does not seem to make the optimal local choice.  Why is the point yo8u choose the best for the next point?  There is a slight change which would make it clearly greedy.

@RossMillikan The way I thought about this, is that if a city isn't in an antennas range, by adding the antenna so that the city is barely in range, then you get some extra space on the right of the city, that can possibly cover some other cities as well.  If there are no other cities there, no problem, we go to the next city to do the same. Because the algorithm is running for every city its complexity is O(n).  What do you mean with the point I choose being best for the next point?

Your algorithm is clearly O(n).  I would argue it is not clearly greedy in that you should choose a point that covers the maximum number of uncovered cities at each stage.  This assumes that there is a fixed time to search for the point that satisfies it.  As with many of these questions it doesn't say whether that is true.
